# Weird Time Difference in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL table as mentioned below which contains 1 record for every 30 minutes executed along with some other columns -

```
ID | dt
1  | 2015-08-08 23:30:00.000
2  | 2015-08-08 23:00:00.000
3  | 2015-08-08 22:30:00.000
4  | 2015-08-08 22:00:00.000
5  | 2015-08-08 21:30:00.000
```

I run the following query to get all records from yesterday from SQL Server.

```
select ID, dt from tbl1
WHERE  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dt), 0) >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @StartDate), 0) 
and DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dt), 0) <= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @EndDate), 0)
```

The query runs OK and return results when I send the parameters as `StartDate = '2015-08-08 12:00:00' and EndDate='2015-08-08 06:30:00'` but it returns no records when the `StartDate = '2015-08-08 12:00:00' and EndDate='2015-08-08 06:00:00'` or when EndDate is specifically less than '2015-08-08 06:30:00'. I have run `SELECT GETDATE()` on server and it returns the same time as displayed by the server clock.

**EDIT**

The code executes via a windows service that runs every 30 minutes. The application is assumed to run at 1:00 AM in the morning, retrieve the records from last date and perform actions, but as mentioned the records are returned only after 6:30 AM and currently I am stuck to run the service at 7 AM instead of 1 AM.

When I set the service to run from my local computer, it runs fine at 1 AM and return results but on production server, it doesn't return any records before 6:30 AM.

I have no clues why this difference is taking place. Any help is appreciated.

If you need any more clarifications, I am here to answer them.

Comment: `dt` column is in DateTime Format or varchar format ?

Comment: @Nitesh it works fine for me, it shows all 5 records with both EndDate values.

Comment: @CiucaS, it works for me in my local computer but not on production server which i don't have access to. It runs on prod well but only after 6:30 AM but not before. I am confused because whatever the parameter values are, I am changing all the dt column, startdate, enddate to '2015-08-08 00:00:00' in my query.

Comment: @cha, please read my comment above regarding the query where clause

Comment: Why don't you just use `WHERE dt >= @StartDate and dt <= @EndDate`? What are your all DATEADD/DATEDIFFs for?

Comment: @cha to convert 2015-08-08 23:30:00.000 into 2015-08-08 00:00:00.000. I am passing the parameters from C# code

Comment: why not cast `@StarDate` to `DATE` instead of using `DATEADD`/DATEDIFF`/

Comment: SQLFiddle is not behaving as you describe. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/466aa/5/0 The issue is not uncovered with the sample data you have given. If the results you are getting are using different data than what you show here, you may need to share that for us to help you further.

Comment: @Felix, I will give that a try

Comment: @SQLTactics, even I am confused regarding this. it runs well on my local computer everytime, but fails to run on server between 12:00 and 06:30 hours

Comment: You might need to double-check the data you are running this against on your production server... Try a `SELECT TOP 10 ID, dt FROM ProductionServerName ORDER BY dt DESC` to see what you are looking at. It may not have the timestamps you are expecting...

Comment: @SQLTactics I double checked and it has the exact records as posted here.

Comment: Could this be an issue with timezone your server is in?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I initially thought this, but it doesn't seem to be. GETDATE() and server time via RDP shows almost the same time with 3 minute difference

Comment: Do you mean the db server & your local box are in same timezone? Also, does windows service code use UTC time at all?

Comment: @shahkalpesh, yes the server from where service is running and db server are in same tiemzone. servicecode uses DateTime.Now to get date values

Answer (score 0):

You had initially asked why you receive no records when `@StartDate` is '2015-08-08 12:00:00' and `@EndDate` is '2015-08-08 06:30:00'. Understand that, in this case, `@StartDate` is after `@EndDate`, so you will never get `dt` values greater than `@StartDate` and less than `@EndDate`.

This being said, you evidently want to use the FLOOR of the `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` parameters (i.e. ignore the timepart) rather than use them raw, so what you could do:

- Round down the `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` parameters alone
- Add one day to `@EndDate`
- Select all records from `tbl` where `dt` is between the modified `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`

  - Adjust the operators to include/exclude exact value of `@EndDate` as appropriate

This example assumes that your code is being called as part of a stored procedure, and will select all dates greater than or equal to `@StartDate` but less than `@EndDate` (you won't need to apply the same transformations to `dt`):

```
-- Swap @StartDate and @EndDate values if need be
IF(@StartDate > @EndDate)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempDate DATETIME;
    SET @TempDate = @StartDate;
    SET @StartDate = @EndDate;
    SET @EndDate = @TempDate;
END;

-- Deliberately set @EndDate to one more than specified
-- Example case:
--                Before                   After
--     @StartDate '2015-08-08 06:30:00' => '2015-08-08 00:00:00'
--     @EndDate   '2015-08-08 12:00:00' => '2015-08-09 00:00:00'
SET @StartDate = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,@StartDate),0);
SET @EndDate = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,@StartDate)+1,0);

-- Query
select ID, dt from tbl1
WHERE dt >= @StartDate 
and dt < @EndDate
```

Comment: if I understand you correctly, why am I getting data when startdate='2015-08-08 12:00:00' and enddate = '2015-08-08 07:00:00'

Comment: I had assumed that you wanted to round the start/end dates to an entire  day, and that you wanted to swap `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` if the former was larger than the latter.

Comment: As for why you get data when @StartDate = '2015-08-08 12:00' and @EndDate = '2015-08-08 07:00', a long shot is that your database might be configured to treat times as 12-hour, and that AM is assumed if unspecified – for example, 12:00 (AM) » 0:00 24hr. 
I recommend returning the highest/lowest `dt` values to reinforce your question.

Comment: You can probably tell that I had initially assumed that '12:00' would be 12pm rather than 12_am_. :$

Comment: I initially thought so :)